# How to use critical-css-generator in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, criticalpathcss

Does anyone know how one is suppose to correctly implement [critical-css-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/critical-css-generator) to auto-generate `ciritcal.css` files in Magento2?
I tried to replicate the instructions here:
https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-enable-and-generate-css-critical-path-in-magento-2/

I have added this block of code

```
const critical = require('critical-css-generator');
critical.generate({
    url: 'https://<my website>',
    path: '/var/www/html/m240/app/design/frontend/<my-theme>/web/css/test_critical.css',
    viewport: true
});
```

insdie `module.exports` in the `Gruntfile.js`.
But when I run `grunt exec` this error occurred in the console:

```
no exec targets found.
```

and sometimes seen this error:

```
Unable to resolve source file for frontend/<my-theme>/en_us/css/styles-l.css.less
```

Where is it getting this `styles-l.css.less`?

Can anyone help? I can not find any tutorials online.

What do you think is the best way to generate `critical css` files in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

In your case first, you need to successfully install grunt if not then first install grunt then run the command **grunt exec**
refer to this link for install grunt in Magento 2.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html